# ansible expression to use with with_item

Tags: ansible

I have a variable, more specifically it's the result (registered in a variable with register:) of a set_fact task using with_item, let's named it myvar, and to simply, I only display the relevant part of it.

```
{
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "item": "item1",
            "stdout_lines": [
                [
                    "result line 1",
                    "result line 2"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": "item2",
            "stdout_lines": [
                [
                    "result line 1"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to run a task for each "result line X" that will include in the command the value of "item" and the "result line X" value
I'm not sure how to do this.

if I do

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.item }} , {{ item | json_query('stdout_lines[0][*]') | list }}"
  with_items: "{{ myvar | json_query('results[*]') }}"
```

The following would output

```
item1 ; [u'result line 1',u'result line 2']
item2 ; [u'result line 1']
```

I have both all stdout_lines entries on the same line. so the split of the stdout_lines should happen in the with_item expression

But here I don't find how I could "fetch" all the stdout_lines of all results and at the same time keep the "item" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd have flat `stdout_lines`, you could just do `with_subelements`.

In your case, you need to spice it with JMESPath a bit:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    myvar:
      "results": [
        {
            "item": "item1",
            "stdout_lines": [
               [
                    "result line 1",
                    "result line 2"
               ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "item": "item2",
            "stdout_lines": [
               [
                    "result line 1"
               ]
            ]
        }
      ]
  tasks:
    - command: echo {{ item.0.name }} {{ item.1 }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ myvar.results | json_query('[].{name:item,lines:stdout_lines[]}') }}"
        - lines
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly, just wondering if the second line of with_subelements could use the result of the first with_subelements line ? If so with an expression we could probably do something like  - "{{ dirout | json_query('results[*]') }}" then  - "{{ PREVIOUS_RESULT | json_query('stdout_lines[0][*]') }}" but i did not get it work, I only tested item as PREVIOUS_RESULT

Comment: Second parameter for `with_subelements` should be the _name_, not values. So this lookup can only select items from list in first parameter.